# Facebook App creating issues in Developement mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-unity-sdk

I have created a new facebook app .My application supports two platform Android and Facebook canvas.My problem is when i 
change the development mode to public the app goes live both for Android and facebook canvas.Is there any way possible
that the app goes live only for Android and for facebook Canvas it remains in the development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a Test App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Test Apps have separate platform settings.